# How to reduce disk access?

Tags: hard-disk, power-management, temperature

This is a follow-up question to *[How to reduce temperature on a Dell XPS (L502X)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148731/how-to-reduce-temperature-on-a-dell-xps-l502x)*.

After reading the answer, I noticed that my harddrive is spinning constantly, even when running TLP in bat-mode (mostly default settings, laptop-mode=5).

**What I already do**

- `/tmp` is mounted as a `tmpfs`. AFAIK this is not recommended for `/var/tmp`, is it?
- `TLP` is running with [this configuration](http://pastebin.com/gjGAs0nX)
- `/` and `/boot` are [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) mounted with `commit=15,noatime`
- `/` is mounted from a [LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) partition, is this a problem?

**What I am searching for**

I guess that constant disk access is the major cause of my disk spinning all the time.

Are there any other ways to reduce disk access and/or ways to allow the disk to spin down?

Comment: `iotop` on an idle system can be an indicator of what's accessing the disk all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another, and surprisingly not well-known,
source of the unneeded disk writes in the Linux world. 
And this is the unnecessarily fast write cache writeout.

You can make it much more seldom if you write the following into `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 360000
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 360000
```

On your filesystems, use ext4 (ext3 makes much more hard drive sync), and mount it with the following flags (example fstab line follows):

```
/dev/sda1 / ext4 defaults,noatime,commit=4780,barrier=0,data=writeback,nobarrier,max_batch_time=0 0 1
```

On swap, use a big swap partition
(2 times of your physical RAM – even in current times). 
If you have multiple data partitions
(for example, a system and a home, or a Windows and a Linux),
then make the swap partition between them, near the middle of the disk.

Of course, this has some disadvantages as well:
if an unexpected system shutdown occurs,
you will have a bigger risk of a data damage. 
But if your hardware is okay, your machine is stable,
and you don't like to shut down with five-second-long power buttons,
then everything is okay.

Encrypted filesystems don't have big disk usage overhead. 
They overload the CPU, and not the disk. 
The used disk is exactly the same as if it weren't encrypted,
but the read and write operations
require some (not really much) additional CPU computation as well. 
Thus, LUKS is not a problem.

Comment: The free place of swapped out pages can be used as cache. This is the cause of the surprising situation, that enabling swap in general makes your system _faster_. It is the same if you have ssd or not. It doesn't have anything to do with the speed of the storage, and of course it also doesn't mean that swap were faster, as the same amount of physical memory. I didn't said any similar.

Comment: I am not entirely sure that this won't kill my system :) ... especially `nobarrier` is AFAIK not recommended for productive systems, is it?

Comment: @Florian nobarrier is not so important. What I consider really important, is the automatic write cache sync feature of the ext2/3/4 after every _5_ _seconds_. I consider this as a terrible default setting. Luckily it can be changed to a much bigger value (imho, write cache has to be written out only if there is no more ram -- to minimize disk usage). I had productive system which were better with a nobarrier flag (because their disk weren't overload any more).

Answer (score 0):

The best would be to replace your hard drive with an [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive). Usually in every laptop you can change the hard disk drive (HDD) without any trouble. This will speed up your laptop and reduce power consumption a lot and will remove annoying HDD noise.

Answering your original question: in fact the HDD only consumes 3-5 watts (SSD <1 watt) while the CPU consumes 30 watts, the motherboard 20 watts and memory like 5 watts and the video card something like that.

So, first you need to find out which part of your notebook really consumes so much power. One of the ways is to open it and touch (carefully, never touch any contacts, only HDD itself, cooling mechanism and never ever touch power source) every component. Most heated part would be the part which consumes most energy.

I can guess that your temperature is caused by 3D effects in your window manager. Try something more lightweight - [LXDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE) or [Window Maker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_Maker). Shut down your X11 and check if the computer will still be hot while all you have is a console. Check usual top, and if anything is there, decide if you really need it.

My [ThinkPad X220](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad_X_Series#X220) is totally cold while I am doing something like web browsing (unless there is lot of [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash)) and text editing. But you can't avoid a hot laptop if you run any 3D GL stuff or 100% CPU load.

Comment: Part of the reason why I opened this question is that (feeling on the surface) the HDD is the hottest part of the laptop.

Comment: As it has no active or passive cooling this hot is stacked over long time. Find out model of your HDD via `smartctl /dev/sda -a` and search internet if it has any kind of performance vs power tuning.

Comment: You can do kind of test if your hdd is really case of your hot laptop - boot some live-cd/live-usb like knoppix and completely power off your hdd. Check if your laptop will still be hot or not.

Comment: ssd-s are very fast compared to hdd-s, and they don't have a seek time. It is true. But they are still far too slow from the speed of the normal memory. This is because the situation about the swap isn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use fatrace (file access trace) program to check which process is writing to the disk, and remove those you don't really need.

Comment: (1) `fatrace` is not automatically included in Linux.  How would the user install it if it wasn’t already installed? (2) How would one use `fatrace` to get the kind of information you’re describing? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete. … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. access ≠ write. Processes unnecessarily *reading* from the disk could be part of the problem, too.